# get rid of http 304 errors in fiddler

Tags: http

How to get rid of 304 error

Request Headers :

```
GET /scripts/PO/wildsearch.html HTTP/1.1
AntiForgeryFormToken: UhKm9yZRWdYkAZYq1vznqO9QT3l2SXwM8RUZz5pbMlHDgHBCSTThPXfEcQxHnZejFFAd8FhJuMv9And8QPaXyj3yWqQjKZhQ6WkuZgh13NS_vc1KC8a4nVcj1NgEIGRJvF3XCzrUHmTOMBRUGQg0nnToUvc1:IQjyx1kU6cOoA9n4YlyTYQnQJkC7UYjZ0q-4sPVrO8O69HeKzjv6ta6lXkq5gAiH2bjotTU4oxbB82TGdlTRyp8ExhsNAYl3vyUJOQphY4DE-WSZwVANpZRAJBEYT_vuwMtBUg2
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Referer: https://mysitename/PO?st=1&reqid=101040506
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, peerdist
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
Host: myorderdev601
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 01:03:19 GMT
If-None-Match: "fed8cda29bf5d01:0"
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: BlueStripe.PVN=a7400000014; ASP.NET_SessionId=4ag54jmm0muvgkldotewbvbv; ai_user=A4B2A069-0853-4081-B52A-4B2200C3A869|2015-09-23T09:27:41.508Z; ai_session=837CA492-BD06-4479-9CD5-D18653829584|1443000464140|1443002984864
X-P2P-PeerDist: Version=1.1
X-P2P-PeerDistEx: MinContentInformation=1.0, MaxContentInformation=2.0
```

Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Expires: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 02:16:10 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 01:03:19 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "fed8cda29bf5d01:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 10:10:05 GMT
```

Comment: 304 is not an error. It's an informational status code.

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP 304 error - Not Modified**

If the client has performed a conditional GET request and access is allowed, but the document has not been modified since the time supplied by the client in the request, the server SHOULD respond with this status code.

There is no error and the HTTP response as should be. This is not an error with **Fiddler** itself.